# How to upload image using Base64 string in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, base64

I am trying to upload image on server as I am getting base64 string when user is uploading image from an android app though I am getting that base64 string on backend but how can I convert it into image and save it into some directory.

Below is my code:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(require('./routes/upload'));

app.listen(port, console.log(`App is running at ${port} port.`));
```

**upload.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.json());
router.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/upload',(req,res) => {

   const name = req.body.base64Image;
   console.log(name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Someone let me know how can I achieve desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use fs to save base64 line to image file

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(uploadPath, fileName), new Buffer(base64, 'base64'))
```

Comment: For TypeScript developers, `new Buffer` has been deprecated. `Buffer.from` should be used instead

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a buffer

```
const base64Data = new Buffer.from(req.body.base64data.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');
```

Then should be able to save or upload to s3 etc

Comment: I want to save this image in `upload` directory so how can I give it a path to `upload`.

Comment: If you want that, you can use multer