# Save the blob url image from using viewer.screenshot() to server/database

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge, bloburls

I used forge viewer api. Viewer.screenshot() to get the image of a component. It returns a blob url as the image. E.g “blob:localhost:3000/afdijhejsbjdjd”. But I need to save this image to my local server, how can I achieve this? Using Nodejs.

How can I change this blob url to a transferable image url?

Comment: You can use the file-saver package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the image Blob URL to a based64 encoded string like the below, and then

```js
function getScreenShotImageBase64(viewer, width, height) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        viewer.getScreenShot(width, height, blobURL => {
            let img = new Image();
            let tmpCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            let ctx = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
            tmpCanvas.width = width;
            tmpCanvas.height = height;

            img.onload = function() {
                // draw viewer image on canvas
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

                resolve(tmpCanvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
            };
            img.src = blobURL;
        });
    });
}

let imageBase64 = await getScreenShotImageBase64(viewer, viewer.container.offsetWidth, viewer.container.offsetHeight);
```

Here is the preview of the result:
[image]

Afterward, send the base64 string to your backend server, and then you can either save the image base64 string to your database,

Or resave the base64 string to file. For example in nodejs.

```js
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(uploadPath, fileName), new Buffer(base64, 'base64'))
```

ref: [How to upload image using Base64 string in NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68653126/how-to-upload-image-using-base64-string-in-nodejs)